# Itemadded current logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        EventFiringEnabled = false;
        SPListItem listItem = properties.ListItem;
        string currentuser = properties.UserLoginName;
        CloneForOtherAssignees(listItem, groupMapping,currentuser);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

I have the above code where currentuser is always SharePoint\System that is Systemaccount. But i want to get the current loggedin user ?. How to get the current loggedin user in Itemadded Event Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, my understanding is that you want to get current user in ItemAdded event.

We can use the following code line to achieve it.

```
SPUser user = properties.Web.CurrentUser;
```

More information:

http://sharepointinstallation.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-get-current-user-permissions-in.html